# Не работает оператор switch

Tags: javascript, html

Пишет "undefined". В чём ошибка?

```
<select size="4" id="season">
    <option disabled>Выберите</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<script>
    var season=document.getElementById('season').value;  
 var result;   
    switch (true) {
    case 1:
    result = ['Зима'];
    break;
    case 2:
    result = ['Весна'];
    break;
    case 3:
    result = ['Лето'];
    break;
    case 4:
    result = ['Осень'];
    break
    }
alert(result);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
var season = document.getElementById('season').value;

var result;

// Преобразуем строкове значение value селекта season в числовое, путём конвертации с помощью оператора '+'
switch (+season) {
  case 1:
    result = ['Зима'];
    break;
  case 2:
    result = ['Весна'];
    break;
  case 3:
    result = ['Лето'];
    break;
  case 4:
    result = ['Осень'];
    break
}
console.log(result);
```

```html
<select size="4" id="season">
  <option disabled>Выберите</option>
  <!-- Добавляем selected как значение по умолчанию, чтобы сразу увидеть эффект -->
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```